# .NET Core Web API SQL Server stored procedures

Tags: .net, sql-server, api, asp.net-core-mvc, infopath

I'm trying to create a .NET Core Web Rest API to connect Infopath forms to it.
The idea that I have is to to capture data from the form and store it to SQL Server, since I want to do some complex things besides just insert to table, I would like to use stored procedures. I would also like to query some information to the forms or/and some reports.

The questions is that I don't know if this is the right approach.

This is my test controller:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using ct3PR.Models;

namespace ct3PR.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class BaseController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly baseContext _context;

        public BaseController(baseContext context) => _context = context;

        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public ActionResult<Base> GetBasesItem(int id)
        {
            var baseItem = _context.BaseItems.Find(id);

            if(baseItem == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return baseItem;
        }
    }
}
```

I already have a test database from which I can query:

```
var baseItem = _context.BaseItems.Find(id);
```

The problem is that I want to send parameters to the stored procedure, but `Find` only searches by primary key. I want to send a range of dates, a name, an id and a range of dates etc.

Could someone guide me in the right direction?

Comment: Use the LINQ `.Where(...)` clause instead of `.Find()` - that allows you to search for any column(s) of the underlying database table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [FromSqlRaw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql#passing-parameters) in EF core to call stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetBaseItems]
@id int = 0,
@name varchar(50)
```

Action:

```
var baseItem = _context.BaseItems.FromSqlRaw("Execute dbo.GetBaseItems @id = {0} ,@name = {1}", id, "itemName");
```

Comment: If I want to return data from de SP, how would my model be? For example if I want to get data and use ToList()

Comment: @FcoLG I do not quite understand...Maybe you could ask a new question by opening a new thread to describe your problem more clearly.(what you have done, current result,expected result..)

Answer (score 0):

```
var itemsList = _context.BaseItems.FromSqlRaw("EXEC SPGetItemsListById @ItemId={0}",Id).ToList();
```